# Set counter per element in jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-plugins, counter

When you set a counter in a jQuery plugin it will be set per instance of the plugin. For instance

```
$.myPlugin(".one");
$.myPlugin(".two");

$.myPlugin = function (el) {
    var counter = 0;
    $(el).click(function () {
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
    });
};
```

Will initiate two counters. ([Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/u2mmc0uq/1/)) However, I'd like to have one counter for each *element* rather than each instance. So, in the fiddle I'd need three counters in total. (Note that the length of elements isn't set in advance so it has to be dynamic.) I thought about adding a unique value to the counter's name, but I'm not entirely sure what value is specific enough so that there can *never* be any duplicates.

Maybe a for loop and an integer to make a distinction, e.g. `counter-1`, `counter-2`, `counter-3`? But how do I loop over instances of the plugin? In other words, how do I make sure that when calling the plugin twice as in the fiddle on three elements in total, I only get three **unique** counters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to custom associated with your elemet

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

*Code*

```
$.myPlugin = function (el) {
    $(el).click(function () {
        var counter = $(this).data('counter') || 1;
        console.log(counter);
        $(this).data('counter', ++counter);
    });
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bw7ucoha/)

I personally would like it this way

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function () {
    this.click(function () {
        var counter = $(this).data('counter') || 1;
        console.log(counter);
        $(this).data('counter', ++counter)

    });
};

$(".one").myPlugin();
$(".two").myPlugin();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/17g18u97/)

Answer (score 0):

Use custom `data-` attributes to set a counter

```
$('button').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-counter', 0);
    $(this).click(function () {
        var counter = parseInt($(this).attr('data-counter'));
        counter++;
        console.log(counter);
        $(this).attr('data-counter', counter);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u2mmc0uq/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use .data()
Try this example:

```
$.myPlugin(".one");
$.myPlugin(".two");

$.myPlugin = function (el) {
    $(el).on('click', function () { // using .on instead of .click to handle dynamicaly added elements
        var counter = parseInt($(this).data('counter')); // using .data() function of jquery to get value from element, it uses data-counter attribute
        counter++; // iterating
        $(this).data('counter', counter); // setting back counter with iterated value
    });
};
```